# How to convert column Year as YYYY in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formatting

I have a column Year in my excel sheet in the format YYYY and initially it is of type Text. I am trying to change the column format to Year but the value is getting modified after formatting.
I am doing this to export the column into my database which is of type Year. Is there a vba code that returns this text field as YYYY?

[image]

Comment: Does this need to be a VBA code? If so, are you interested in a true date value formatted as year or just an integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many different ways to do it, but this will work as a formula (assuming your first column is A):

```
=YEAR("1/1/" & A1)
```

All that does it use the text from column A as a year, and builds a string prefixed with Jan 1, and then converts that to a year.

Then just copy that formula down like normal.

Comment: Thanks this helps!
Final code
Function yrToSQL(dt As Integer) As Variant
yrToSQL = Year("1/1/" & dt)

End Function

Answer (score 0):

To convert a text number as shown in your case, use `=DATE(A1,1,1)`

Col A is formatted as `text` and Col C is formmated as `YYYY`

[image]

Comment: This actually gives me `1/1/2019` in column B.

Comment: Col A is formatted as text and Col C is formmated as YYYY

Comment: I understand, but perhaps he needed the `.Value` to be an `Integer` and not a `Date` - That's how I read it at least. As I stated, there are many ways to do this.

Comment: `As I stated, there are many ways to do this.` yup I agree. I already upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

according to this article you can change your date format in vba :

```
Sub date_and_time()

    'Now => returns the current date and time (02.07.2012 09:09:02)
    date_test = Now()

    'Returns: 02.07.12
    Range("A1") = Format(date_test, "mm.dd.yy")

    'Returns: 7 February 2012
    Range("A2") = Format(date_test, "d mmmm yyyy")

    'Returns: February 7, 2012
    Range("A3") = Format(date_test, "mmmm j, yyyy")

    'Returns: Tue 07
    Range("A4") = Format(date_test, "ddd dd")

    'Returns: February-12
    Range("A6") = Format(date_test, "mmmm-yy")

    'Returns: 02.07.2012 09:09
    Range("A7") = Format(date_test, "mm.dd.yyyy hh:mm")

    'Returns: 2.7.12 9:09 AM
    Range("A8") = Format(date_test, "m.d.yy h:mm AM/PM")

    'Returns: 9H09
    Range("A9") = Format(date_test, "h\Hmm")
```

Comment: Except in this case, the OP's cell is not a date, it is in text format.